# How to display callout in MKPinAnnotationView?

Tags: iphone

I need to display the callout without tapping on the pin in the MKView.
I tried setSelected:animated method call but it doesn't seems to work.

Once the pin is dropped to the map, the callout should be displayed right away.

Comment: The iPhone 3.0 SDK is still under NDA, so I don't know that anyone can reply to this :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MKMapView:selectAnnotation:animated`.